# Excel is ruining my numbers with leading zeros

Tags: excel

We process hundreds of shipments from FedEx, and the tracking numbers go into a CSV. Everything went fine for years until one of our customers decided to use FedEx Smartpost.

The tracking numbers for Smartpost are rather long. Here is one of them: `61299990387420002000`

When this number is placed in Excel, it becomes `61299990387420000000`

We end up with hundreds of shipments all stuck with that false tracking number. It seems Excel is converting the last half of the tracking number to all zeros.

Has anyone encountered this issue, and tips?

I have tried formatting the cell, no luck.

I am serious, copy and paste the first number in Excel and watch Excel automatically ruin the number

Comment: You will need to import it as text not a number as Excel only stores the first 14(I believe) numbers.  Like I said to get around this store it as text and not a number.

Comment: I preformatted the cell as text from `Home` >> `Number` and pasted the tracking number and it worked.

Comment: Brian, which version are you using? That did not work. I also found verification from Microsoft that that will not work either. The field has to be pre formatted to text. And since this is all done programmatically, the only option it to concatenate a string of text onto the numbers.
https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/269370

Comment: @JosephKreifelsII I am using 2013. Are you using VBA to do this or some other way? Can you add a single quote before each tracking number into your program?

Comment: the CSV has the values as you want them.  What you can't do is JUST OPEN The CSV in excel, you have to go though an IMPORT process and define the field as TEXT on the import

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Based on comments made (Scott Craner nailed it in a comment), I think you're directly opening the CSV in excel.  You can't do this.  Excel will do it's best to interpret each data type.  since the tracking numbers are numbers it will bring them in as general and then you encounter the ***feature*** mentioned in earlier answers (@JosephKreifelsII  err... yours...).  To work around this you must IMPORT the document.  ***DO NOTsimply open the CSV in Excel***.

To save some headache you may even want to go as far as removing the .csv file extension association from Excel so you're forced to import it. (Tie it to notepad or notepad ++ or some other text editor instead!)

You must open an excel document then IMPORT the CSV

1. Open Excel
2. Go to Data Tab
3. Select from Text
4. Select csv file.
5. select import button
6. select delimited
7. select next button
8. unselect tab and select comma
9. select next button

   10. define the data type for each of the columns (text for your tracking no)
   11. Select finish. Data will now be in excel without losing the last numbers.

[image]

You may be able to record a macro to do this, I've not tried.

Comment: That's amazing. The might help for the end process.

Comment: I've worked with VBA in the past. I'll look at writing a script to to do this. I'm waiting to see if we can get by without opening the CSV. Things might be different as we continue to move towards the future. Thank you for this suggestion.

Comment: @JosephKreifelsII Glad to help Best of luck!

Answer (score 1):

I have encountered this problem and I avoided VBA code by making my database system prefix the tracking number with an "F" so that Excel reads it as a text field.

Answer (score 0):

https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/269370

Microsoft confirms this is purposely done.

IN order to avoid, you must preformat the cell to TEXT, and only then successfully paste the number in.

Our CSVs are created from the database all programatically. It's output as unformatted. So there isn't much we can do.

I've tested opening the CSV with notepad++, and things looked fine. The only option is to NOT look at the file with Excel

Comment: Can you not preformat the column in Excel before importing?

Comment: No. The database opens a stream to a new file and outputs the POs and tracking numbers into the newly created CSV. We don't have access to the CSV before hand (as it wont exist).